# Different relative time labels in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: support, user-interface

On Stack Overflow, when viewing the `Questions` section, questions listed on the that page:

- in Chrome are displayed as "*modified* 17 secs ago" near the question
- in Firefox are displayed as "*asked* 17 secs ago" near the question.

Why is a different text displayed in different browsers?

Comment: Questions arriving through the websocket update have the *modified* label and posts after a page refresh have the *asked* label.

Comment: Also, if you are in *active* tab then you will see *modified* and when you are in *newest* tab you will see either *asked* or *modified* (as @juergen said).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing differences between how the posts were loaded. I see this in Chrome right now:

[image]

where your post was loaded via the live refresh (websocket) feature. Once I reload the page, I see:

[image]

(and yes, the other question was indeed closed between reloads).

Comment: For other readers: Things other than "asked" also typically show on pages other than [newest](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) for example the [Active](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) page shows "modified" when a question is edited, or an answer posted etc.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I am giving the OP the benefit of the doubt and presume that at the very least he is looking at the same tab in both browsers.

Comment: That's fine, just pointing it out for others. Depending on the default tab people might typically see one or the other (or both of course).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Got it thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it thanks..